# SSH into server on VPN from remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn

At work I have been using ssh to run computation on an on-site server. Using a command like so:

```
ssh -X myusername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Now that I will be working from off-site with my own machine, IT created for me my own VPN credentials. Using what they gave (gateway, groupname and pwd, accountname and pwd) I was able to connect to the VPN by vpnc on the network manager on Ubuntu.

How would I access the same server as before? The above command seems to point to the Internet IP address (output below) which would not be what I want. How do I connect to the local server IP under the VPN?

```
me@mymachine:~$ ssh -X myusername@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
The authenticity of host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

**EDIT:** I entered `yes` and it worked. Strange, since it didn't work when I tried it before. My thanks to user Zondo.

Comment: If you're sure that's the right IP address, say `yes` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've made an initial connection, the key is saved to a file, typically: ~/.ssh/known_hosts  You will only be asked for your password with successive attempts.